# SVG renders weirdly on macOS Safari 15.2

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an animated SVG,

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #30363d;
}
```

```html
<svg width="36" height="36" fill="#fff" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10.72,19.9a8,8,0,0,1-6.5-9.79A7.77,7.77,0,0,1,10.4,4.16a8,8,0,0,1,9.49,6.52A1.54,1.54,0,0,0,21.38,12h.13a1.37,1.37,0,0,0,1.38-1.54,11,11,0,1,0-12.7,12.39A1.54,1.54,0,0,0,12,21.34h0A1.47,1.47,0,0,0,10.72,19.9Z">
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      calcMode="linear"
      dur="0.75s"
      values="0 12 12;360 12 12"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
    ></animateTransform>
  </path>
</svg>
```

It renders perfectly on every other browser except Safari 15.2 on macOS. I can't figure out why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform#browser_compatibility reports Safari support for `animateTransform` as "unknown", so I would guess that perhaps means no support in this instance ...?

Comment: Looks fine on my Safari?

Comment: @Simp4Code version?

Comment: @FunnelScr Version 15.1 (17612.2.9.1.20)